# C++ IBM i Access API Running remote commands and getting output

Tags: c++, command, ibm-midrange

IBM i Access API for C++ lets you run server commands for example (**DSPSYSSTS** Displaying system status):

```
cwbSV_ErrHandle msgHandle; //Error Handle
cwbSV_CreateErrHandle(&msgHandle); //Create Error Handle
int code = cwbRC_RunCmd(SystemData::hxSystem, "DSPSYSSTS", msgHandle); //Run command

//Command ran successfully
if(code == CBW_OK){
   int code = cwbSV_GetErrText(msgHandle, returnTxt, 1024, NULL);
   //code value is CWBSV_NO_ERROR_MESSAGES
}
```

I can retrieve error messages thrown by the server after command run. But how can I retrieve the command output? If I run a "DSP" (Display) command, I'm obviously wanting to get the output display.

Comment: DSPSYSSTS should create spooled output if run via cwbRC_RunCmd(). It could technically be retrieved, but the [Retrieve System Status (QWCRSSTS) API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/apis/qwcrssts.htm?lang=en) is intended to be used for program access to such data. Formats SSTS0100, SSTS0200 and SSTS0300 together would return all DSPSYSSTS data.

Answer (score 1):

DSP type commands by definition send their output to the 5250 data stream which is then interpreted by a 5250 emulator in order to properly paint a display.  It's not at all like stdout, which means that intercepting output meant for a display will require a fair amount of work.

The traditional answer is to use an API which returns the information in a form intended to be read by a program.  In the case of system status, that's probably the [Retrieve System Status (QWCRSSTS) API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qwcrssts.htm).  One way to make this easy on yourself is to write a stored procedure and call that instead of directly invoking the API from the client.

Another alternative is to DSPSYSSTS OUTPUT(*PRINT), then read the spooled file.  It'll be easier to parse than the raw 5250 output but it can and does change between releases so the API is a more consistent interface.

If you really want to screen scrape the output from DSPSYSSTS, you'll need to learn about the 5250 protocol, which is complex enough that I don't think it can be explained in a forum like this.  On the other hand, Albert York has written a program called [TNAPI](http://www.albertyork.yolasite.com/samples.php) which might fit your needs.

Comment: Interesting info. Have you tried "TNAPI"? Where can I get examples? It seems to be what I need. I need to install an RPG program in IBM i right? Thanks.

Comment: I have not used TNAPI.  If I had this problem I'd probably write a stored procedure that calls the API and returns the specific information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Scott Klement explaning](http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/callc.html) to translate [Retrieve System Status (QWCRSSTS) API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/qwcrssts.htm) into C++ code. This way you dont need rpg at all.